# Why is my "Character" still moving through the gameObject instead of the game object destroying

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't seem to get the collision with `Character` to cause the game object to destroy itself.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollectItem: MonoBehaviour
{
  void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision){
  if(collision.gameObject.name == "Character"){
      Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of reasons:

1. You might not have a collider attached to the item you want to collect.
2. You might not have a collider attached to your Character object.
3. One or both colliders might be set as Triggers (in which case only one should be a trigger, you will need to use the OnTriggerEnter method and make sure the trigger object has a Rigidbody component)
4. The name of the character object is misspelled.

As a side note, when comparing strings you should always use the Equals method i.e collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Character").  That is not your problem here, though.